# .apply without thisArgument

Tags: javascript

I want to give dynamic parameters to a function and that works great with .apply. However, I do not need to give this function a "this". So I just give a empty string as first parameter to .apply:

```
myfunc.apply("", dynamicargs);
```

Is this a way to go or are there better ways?

Comment: It's fine, `null` would be more descriptive, but it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a way to go or are there better ways?

[Pass `null` instead:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

> Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a function in non-strict mode code, `null` and `undefined` will be replaced with the global object, and primitive values will be boxed.

Then the function behaves exactly as if called as

```
myfunc(arg1, arg2, ...);
```

It probably won't make a difference, but it would be more "correct".